# asmx web services in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-5, asmx

I have added the asmx web service using service reference in my project in MVC5 and then I have added this (Service1.Service1SoapClient service = new Service1.Service1SoapClient("Service1Soap");) so I can use web methods. I can use  string web methods.

Specifically, I have a number of my web methods with actions like edit, create etc that have to do with a local database that i created on web service.

Is it possible to use those web methods in MVC?? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Service Reference creates proxy class. You just use that proxy to call web service methods. Look like you are on the right track. Where did you get stuck exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @Win : For example, here is a simple web method:
public DataTable  Test()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * from tblStudents";
            return Read(query);
        }
and Read(query) I have declared it as private DataTable Read(string query)  that return dataTable;   
From ASP.NET is very easy to use this because I just declare: DataTable Student = new Service1.Service1SoapClient().Test(); and then some code ... But in MVC  I'm so confused I don't know how to do this? 

In fact, this is a task that it's an obligation for me to do with aspx web services.

Comment: @Win  Do u have any idea??

Comment: @Egzona You just need to call `DataTable Student = new Service1.Service1SoapClient().Test();` inside **Action** method. In Action method, you just renders **Model** to **View**. Calling web service from **ASP.Net MVC** is basically same as **ASP.Net Web Form**.